# Convert CSV With Only Headers to XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, csv

I am trying to convert CSV files to XML. The code I am currently using is:

```
XElement xml = new XElement(rootElementName,
                lines.Where((line, index) => index > 0)
                    .Select(line => new XElement(itemElementName,
                        line.Split(',').Select((column, index) => new XElement(headers[index], column)))));
```

an this works great. The issue I am facing is that I am trying to load a CSV file that only has a single row which contains the column headers. I would like to create an empty XML which contains the empty items:

```
<XML>
    <item>
        <column1></column1>
        <column2></column2>
    </item>
</XML>
```

And so forth. I am not great with lambda's, so I am not sure if there is a way to do what I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, after poking it a bit I got it to work:

```
if (lines.Length == 1)
            {
                xml = new XElement(rootElementName,
                lines.Select(line => new XElement(itemElementName,
                        line.Split(',').Select((column, index) => new XElement(headers[index], "")))));
            }
            else
            {
                xml = new XElement(rootElementName,
                    lines.Where((line, index) => index > 0)
                        .Select(line => new XElement(itemElementName,
                            line.Split(',').Select((column, index) => new XElement(headers[index], column)))));
            }
```

This does what I want, but feel free to let me know if there is a better way. Thanks

Comment: How to transform any kind of csv file to xml based on its header and then display the xml in parent, child node format. i dont have to use any hardcoded values while constructing xml file. say i want to generate the xml file based on student class. so each student will have name ,id based on class. and ithis kind of logic will work for any kind of Csv to xml file creation. Hope you got my requirement.